# How do I exit immediately in conditional command?

Tags: bash, shell

At first, we can use `set -e` to exit the shell script immediately if any command failed(exit with non-zero code).

But, how can I exit it immediately in a conditional statement? For example:

```
set -xe

_if_error() {
  'run a bad command' # should exit immediately for this command does not exist
  echo -e "\033[31mUnexpected execution\033[0m"
}

if ! _if_error; then
  echo 'ok'
else
  echo 'bad'
fi
```

I hope the script echo `ok`, and do not echo red `Unexpected execution`.